# Problema de lógica en php

Tags: php

Hola estoy haciendo un algoritmo en php que reciba un numero separado por puntos y un valor(con dos decimales) y que este se conecte a la base de datos y me los ordene de la siguiente manera
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

pero lo que necesito es que me los ordene(numero) y sume(value) de la siguiente manera comenzando con el numero padre 4.01.00.00.00 y la sumatorias de los demás hijos 4.01.XX.XX.XX

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

el código que he echo es el siguiente pero no logro dar con la solución lógica a mi problema:

```
$number = "4.01.05.04.01";
        $value = 2.10;
        $parts = explode(".", $number);
        $sum = 0;
        $result = array();
        for($i=1; $i<count($parts); $i++) {
            $current = implode(".", array_slice($parts, 0, $i+1));
            for($j=$i+1; $j<count($parts); $j++) {
                $current .= ".00";
            }
            if(end($parts) > 0 OR prev($parts) > 0) { // Si es el número pasado
                
                $result[] = array($current, $value);
            } else {$sum += $value;
                $result[] = array($current, $sum);
            }
        }
        
        //Conexión a la base de datos
        $servername = "localhost";
        $username = "root";
        $password = "";
        $dbname = "test";
        
        // Crear conexión
        $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
        // Verificar conexión
        if ($conn->connect_error) {
            die("La conexión falló: " . $conn->connect_error);
        }
        
        foreach($result as $res) {
            $n = $res[0];
            $v = $res[1];
            // Verificar si el número ya existe en la base de datos
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM numeros_ordenados WHERE numero='$n'";
            $result = $conn->query($sql);
            if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
                // Actualizar valor del número en la base de datos
                $sql = "UPDATE numeros_ordenados SET value='$v' WHERE numero='$n'";
                if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE)
                {
                    echo "El valor del número $n ha sido actualizado en la base de datos.";
                } else {
                    echo "Error al actualizar el valor del número $n en la base de datos: " . $conn->error;
                }
            } else {
                // Insertar nuevo número en la base de datos
                $sql = "INSERT INTO numeros_ordenados (numero, value) VALUES ('$n', '$v')";
                if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
                    echo "El número $n ha sido insertado en la base de datos.";
                } else {
                    echo "Error al insertar el número $n en la base de datos: " . $conn->error;
                }
            }
        }
        
        $conn->close();
```

Lo que he echo solo me genera lo que se aprecia en la imagen (1)

Comment: ¿Qué tipo de dato es `value`?.

Comment: Hola, es decimal

Comment: ¿No te sirve ordenar desde la consulta: `ORDER BY value DESC, numero`?

Comment: No, ya lo he intentado así pero esta no me genera lo que busco, lo que busco es que la terminación de cada valor numero (4.01.01.01.01.xx) me coloque el valor que desee y los demás hacia arriba (xx.xx.xx.xx.00) sean las sumas de los demás, como la imagen(2) que coloque

Comment: ¿Es una sumatoria por segmentos contables? Agrega un script para crear datos de ejemplo.

Comment: Si algo así, el contexto de todo esto es que estoy estudiando programación(solo llevo un mes), y para mis ejercicios de lógica tome algo que en mi país(Venezuela) llaman el clasificador de presupuesto que es algo que lleva el orden y contabilidad de esa forma a sector de educación y salud, pero mi nivel de lógica no llegas hasta lo que deseo hacer

Comment: No uses `prev()`, esa función -al igual que `end()`- mueven el apuntador interno del arreglo y así como lo tienes siempre regresarán lo mismo. Considera usar los índices del arreglo.

Comment: Vale, colocare los indices $parts[x]